# JavaFx ImageView no cambia la imagen

Tags: java, javafx

Esto es en JavaFX:

Tengo un dashboard de productos que (en una barra lateral) muestra la foto del producto actualmente seleccionado en un TableView. Los datos de ese producto seleccionado se pueden editar en una ventana adicional. La edición permite cambiar la fotografía del producto. Este cambio se realiza sobrescribiendo la foto original (o sea, cambia el contenido del archivo, no su nombre ni su ubicación en disco).

Mi problema es que cuando se cambia esa foto, al salir de la ventana de edición, el dashboard no refleja ese cambio, sigue mostrando la foto anterior (lo cual tiene cierto sentido pues el nombre del archivo sigue siendo el mismo), por lo que primero "limpio" la foto que ya se muestra haciendo

```
fotoProducto.setImage(new Image(null)); // Esto si funciona
```

Y luego cargo de nuevo el archivo:

```
fotoProducto.setImage(new Image("archivo.jpg"));
```

Sin embargo, el dashboard sigue mostrando la foto anterior y no la nueva.

Como dije, lo que cambia es el contenido de la imagen, no su nombre en disco (por ejemplo, siempre se llamará "imagen1.jpg"). ¿Hay algún tipo de caché que daba limpiarse o alguna manera de forzar al ImageView a refrescar y reconocer el cambio en el contenido del archivo?

Gracias por cualquier idea.

Comment: Utiliza fotoProducto.repaint();

Comment: @Julian-Solarte La clase ImageView no tiene un método repaint()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luego de dos semanas por fin encontré una respuesta:

En lugar de cargar las imágenes usando `fotoProducto.setImage(new Image("archivo.jpg"));`, ahora lo hago asi:

```
File img = new File("archivo.jpg");
InputStream isImage = (InputStream) new FileInputStream(img);
imageView.setImage(new Image(isImage));
```

Eso solucionó el problema.